# Py/Django unit testing with Selenium: Do I have any dead links?

Tags: django, selenium, testing, python-unittest

as far as I am aware, selenium cannot return http status codes.
What I want to do is click all certain links on a page and test for any broken links. Seems like unittest provides the machinery for getting the status codes, but selenium has the nifty find_element/xpath functions.
Is LiveServerTestCase what I should be looking at?

No code here.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML isn't too difficult in Python. You can use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.parser.html) to find all the `<a hrefs="">` values in an HTML string/file like so

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

html = '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><h1>Parse me!</h1>'\
       '<a href="http://example.com/"></a></body></html>'

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if 'href' in attrs:
            print("Link:", attrs['href'])

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(html)
```

So, yes, UnitTest seems to be the tool to use.